# Can't connect to docker container with Web Browser

Tags: docker

I ma new to docker and try to start a django app with my own image.
It seems like the djano web server runs but I am unable to see connect with my host maschine.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
RUN python3 /code/manage.py makemigrations
RUN python3 /code/manage.py migrate

EXPOSE 8000
CMD python3 /code/manage.py runserver
```

To build the image:
`docker build -t $USER/myapp .`

To run the image I already tried:
`docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 $USER/myapp`
Result of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES  
f2f40d835fad        user/myapp   "/bin/sh -c 'pytho..."   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   amazing_leakey
```

`docker run -rm -it -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 $USER/myapp`

Result of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
6c9ab64419a9        christian/musicweb   "/bin/sh -c 'pytho..."   11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       127.0.0.1:8000->8000/tcp   practical_borg
```

`docker run --rm -it $USER/myapp`

Result of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f8803e5e7439        christian/musicweb   "/bin/sh -c 'pytho..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        8000/tcp            upbeat_goldwasser
```

I always get this output, so django seems to run fine:

> Performing system checks...
>   System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>   September 22, 2018 - 19:02:58
>   Django version 2.1.1, using settings 'myapp.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

What did I miss, thanks for your help.

Comment: EXPOSE is not needed. -p should be enough. not a solution still

Comment: So would it not be better to not use __-p__

Comment: -p is needed . EXPOSE is for inter-container communication

Comment: open another CLI and `docker exec <container id> curl -L localhost:8000` what do you get?